# Programmatically fire UI event for unit testing

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, events, treeview

I'm working on a winforms project in visual studio express that involves clicking on different nodes of a treeview to show different forms, which I took care of by creating a handler for the AfterSelect event. Since I don't have VS Ultimate or Premium, I can't use coded UI tests. To unit test this, I tried programmatically changing the selected node of the treeview like so

`treeview1.SelectedNode = Nodes[0].Nodes[1]`
and checking the text of a label which switches based on the selected node.

The afterSelect event doesn't seem to be firing, and I've tried giving the treeview focus, I've tried calling `.Select()`, and I've tried setting the `HideSelection` property to `false`. I've looked here and on other sites and those are the only suggestions so far that seemed viable for my situation.

I was wondering what I need to do in order to get the AfterSelect event to fire within unit testing?

Comment: Could you provide the code for your unit test and the method you are testing possibly? I think that would help us visualize what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I could put the unit test method on here, but the method I'm testing is huge. I can give you a quick run down of whats going on though.

The unit test is checking to see if a label's text is being changed. In my original source code, where I handle the AfterSelect event, I use
`this.label1.text = e.Node.Text`

it's default text is label1, and Nodes[0].Nodes[1] is "Power". So for the unit test, I'm using the statement

`Assert.AreEqual("Power", label1.Text);`

label1 is private in the main form, I access it using a property I defined within the main form's source code

Comment: Are you using Moq or another mocking framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't really unit testing, and that's the core of the problem. You are supposed to test an independent unit of code, but here you have strong dependence on the UI (it's both the input and the output).
You should separate your logic from the UI, and just test the logic independently.

To separate the logic from the UI as its output, create an interface, for example:

```
  public interface ITreeUIOutput
  {
      void ChangeLabel(string nodeName, string text);
  }
```

Then your logic code will have a hook for the UI to use as input, and it will call the output interface:

```
  public class TreeModifier
  {
       private ITreeUIOutput _ui;

       public TreeModifier(ITreeUIOutput ui)
       {
            _ui = ui;
       }

       public void AfterSelect(string nodeName, string nodeText)
       {
            _ui.ChangeLabel(nodeName, nodeText + "New");
       }
  }
```

Once the code is separated, you can use a mocking library (like Moq) to test your logic:

```
 Mock<ITreeUIOutput> uiMock = new Mock<ITreeUIOutput>();
 string nodeName = "MyNode";
 string nodeText = "MyText";

 TreeModifier tree = new TreeModifier(uiMock.Object);
 tree.AfterSelect(nodeName, nodeText);

 //Here we test that ChangeLabel was called once (and only once) with the correct parameters, meaning our logic worked!
 uiMock.Verify(c => c.ChangeLabel(nodeName, nodeText + "New"), Times.Once);
```